# Recall test run history at any time in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, ide

During automatic test execution in IntelliJ IDEA the **Run** tab of the IDE is *dedicated* to test results and is possible to recall old test execution results using the *"Clock"/Test history* button.

But how can I recall these results if I then run another "activity" (like Maven build or application launch)?

Is there a way to access the test data when *Run* tab is no longer in "test mode"?

**NOTE** I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve old test results under the `Run | Test History` menu item.